# Do you regain consciousness immediately after rolling a 20 on a death saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw

In the PHB, it mentions that upon rolling a 20 on a death saving throw, you regain 1 HP. However, are you still unconscious after receiving this 1 HP? Additionally, if magically healed (by cure wounds or whatever), do you gain consciousness immediately?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, if you regain hp either by rolling a 20 on a death save or by any other method, you will gain consciousness immediately.

> If damage reduces you to 0 hit points and fails to
>   kill you, you fall unconscious (see appendix A). This
>   unconsciousness ends if you regain any hit points.

Comment: Worth noting the death save in 5E is at the *start* of your turn (unlike 4E where it was at end). So yes you wake up immediately and can act that turn.

Comment: Of course, remember that you're (most likely) still prone and so you'll probably need to use **half your speed** to stand up. (PHB 190-191)

Comment: @NeilSlater Am I wrong in thinking that the PHB says a DST is all you can do on your turn?

Comment: @NielSlater Do you have a reference for that? The way I have always seen it ran in 5e by man DMs was that it was at the end of turn so that if you saved that was all you could do

Comment: System Reference document, P98 and PHB page 197: "Whenever you start your turn with 0 hit points, you must make a special saving throw" - no mention at all of it being the *only* thing you can do, the inability to act is covered due to being unconscious.  But a character stops being unconscious when gaining hit points. There are no references I can find saying a DST is the *only* thing that can be done on a turn - @PremierBromanov can you find such a reference?

Comment: @NeilSlater I do not, I am entirely unsure if that's the way we've played it or not. It's been awhile since I've crit a DST. I'll look into it when I can, but likely too busy to. If someone wants to take a crack at it they can. However, initial reading of the passage leads me to believe you are correct. It's not an action and it doesn't say its the only thing you can do.

Comment: Thank you. I had thought this was the case, but it isn't exactly explicit.

Comment: Worth noting that typically, saving throws don't use your action, in particular because they often happen when it's not your turn. (DST an exception to that last.)